# How to grab a commit from another branch without a merge?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

At face value, this seems like a textbook use case for cherry pick.  Googling around, I find statements like:

> Cherry picking in Git means to choose a commit from one branch and apply it onto another.
>
> The command git cherry-pick commit applies the changes introduced by the named commit on the current branch.

So I go and try it... and half my file turns into merge conflicts (a regular merge turns a further 8 other files into merge conflicts, so that's not useful either).  The commit in question only changes ~5 lines or so, and not half the file.

For context, the 2 branches look roughly like:

1. P -> [20 commits] -> A -> B = other_branch
2. P -> [30 unrelated commits] -> C = my_branch

The only thing commit B does is to change ~5 lines in foo.py
I want to cherry pick those changes into commit C, but apparently cherry pick hates me.

I found these other related questions:

[What use case is git cherry-pick useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69685815/what-use-case-is-git-cherry-pick-useful-for)

[Issue with cherry pick: changes from previous commits are also applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530381/issue-with-cherry-pick-changes-from-previous-commits-are-also-applied)

They suggest that the above quotes are actually lies, and cherry pick is actually a fancy 3 way merge?  I think one of them (or another question) offers the following solution:

```
git show commitB > patch.txt
git apply patch.txt
```

I also tried

```
git diff commitA commitB | git apply
```

but all I get is

```
error: patch failed: foo.py:20
error: foo.py: patch does not apply
```

Is manual copy pasta my only solution?

On a related note, what/when is git cherry pick good for?  I can't think of any good use cases.  If 2 branches differ slightly, a plain old merge does almost the same thing.  If 2 branches differ greatly (my case), cherry pick just flops.

Comment: If `git cherry-pick` tells you that there is a conflict, then there is a conflict. Manual intervention of some form will be required, there's no way around that. The form of manual intervention is at your descretion. You can just copy-and-paste the code, or resolve the conflict, or hack the patch until it can be applied.

Comment: @j6t Thanks, even if it's not the informative answer, it does answer my question directly - I'm basically fcked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why you are getting conflicts :*

suppose you are in the following situation :

```
--*--*--*--*--*--H <- HEAD, mybranch (your current state)
   \
    *--*--x--y--* <- some/otherbranch
             ^
       (the commit you want to cherry pick)
```

If you run `git cherry-pick <y>`, git will try to reconcile :

- the changes introduced by the commit, that is : the diff `x -> y`
- with changes on your branch : the diff between `x -> H`

So : if the patch says "there is a change at line 22", and your branch *also* introduce changes on line 22 (when compared to `x`), you are bound to have conflicts.

(actually, it's even if you have changes *near* line 22, you will have conflicts)

---

*How to fix conflicts :*

A decent enough way to fix conflicts is to edit them in a 3-way diff viewer, such as `kdiff3` or `winmerge` or `meld` or ...

You can ask `git` to open the 3 way diff merge tool for you, by running `git mergetool` :

```
git mergetool
# if you want to select a specific mergetool:
git mergetool --tool=vimdiff
```

If the commit you chose only introduced a few changes, fixing the conflicts will look a lot like :

- mainly take the content from current commit ("ours" side)
- include the few changes inroduced in commit `y`

In the end : you get to choose what content gets committed as the "correct" version for including the changes from commit `y`.

Comment: Great answer overall.  Unfortunately, I lack the reputation to give you a proper upvote; I hope the answer accept is good enough for now.

But for my 2ndary question: what is a cherry pick good for?  If Alice works on her branch, and Bob works on his branch, they'll diverge in quick order, in which case the cherry pick will fail badly as I found out.  Are we supposed to merge every 3 commits?

Comment: if Alice and Bob are working on closely related features, perhaps they should make sure to sync their work more often than on standard, separate developments. If you have this issue with any two developers working on separate issues or features, this probably is an indication that some file in your repo is too central, and gets modified too often. You will probably need to think of some way to change you workflow make this issue disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Cherry-pick cannot simply "copy a commit". A commit in Git references a *tree* and a tree is a *full snapshot* of your complete project's files (and implicitly, directories).

When you perform a cherry-pick, Git will first compute the "changes of this commit" (basically running `git diff thatcommit thatcommit^`) and then try to re-apply those changes to your current HEAD. Usually, this works well enough; given that the files changed in the picked-from commit have not diverged too much from your current HEAD commit. If the same lines (or nearby lines) have changed in both branches, Git cannot automatically merge (or cherry-pick) the changes. Simply because it cannot detect which are the "correct" changes.

So when you say that the file has only 5 lines changed, then the cherry-pick should apply cleanly. Unless of course, more lines have changed, e.g. line-endings were normalized in one branch, but not the other (command line flags help with that).

To quickly find out how much your file has diverged on both branches, run diff: `git diff branchA branchB -- foo.py`.

If more lines have changed (and from your description, it sounds like that), you are probably better off re-applying those changes manually. But since you claim that only a few lines have changed, that shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: It seems clear at this point the common descriptions of cherry pick are total lies.  Indeed, the branches have diverged rather substantially (in no small part because I removed a loop, so several 100 lines are now reduced by 1 indent).  This still leaves my 2ndary question: what is cherry pick good for?  Branches diverge very rapidly unless there's a merge every 3 commits or something like that.  In any case I can think of, either 1) cherry pick will fail 2) a plain old merge does the same thing.

Comment: @pierrecurie 100 lines moved by 1 indent is 100 changed lines. Git doesn't understand the "structure" of your program. Git doesn't care if it is Java or Python or Brainfuck. Git cares about _lines_. If you change a line, it is a changed line, regardless if you think the change is "small" or "irrelevant". Git does not and can not know. And it is better to leave such difficult decisions to humans than to attempt to come up with "a" solution that might totally not be what you want. Cherry-pick is good for copying commits (re-applying the commit's patch and using the same commit message) if you …

Comment: … have similar trees to start with. Cherry-pick is not intended as a magic way to resolve conflicts between different branches. Merge on the other hand will merge your commit histories and keep both sides of the history. Cherry-pick will copy the commit, effectively duplicating it. Each tool for its intended use case. I cannot agree with your point about having to merge every 3 commits. Cherry-pick can work very well even for branches that are thousands of commits apart. If you change all files in one branch, but not in the other, cherry-pick will fail (of course). But merge would too.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I guess we're just using git poorly.  but that's probably another question for another time